# Programmatically insert an image with caption

Tags: 7, media

I'm trying to attach programmatically an Image with caption to my node.
I'm using [image_field_caption](https://drupal.org/project/image_field_caption) module.

```
    $node = node_load($nid);

    $path = "images/gallery_articolo/".$value['foto'];
    $filetitle = $value['desc'];
    $filename = $value['foto'];

    $file_temp = file_get_contents($path);
    $file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, 'public://' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

    $node->field_steps['und'][($value['order'] - 1)] = array(
        'image_field_caption' => array( 'value' => $value['desc'], 'format' => 'full_html'),
        'fid' => $file_temp->fid,
        'filename' => $file_temp->filename,
        'filemime' => $file_temp->filemime,
        'uid' => 1,
        'uri' => $file_temp->uri,
        'status' => 1
    );

    node_save($node);
```

I followed the stucture seen in devel, but I have a lot of issues..

This is the recent log entry:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'caption' cannot be null: 
INSERT INTO {field_image_field_caption_revision} (field_name, entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, caption, caption_format) 
VALUES (
:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8), (:db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13, :db_insert_placeholder_14, :db_insert_placeholder_15, :db_insert_placeholder_16, :db_insert_placeholder_17); 
Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => field_steps [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 455 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 863 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => article [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => field_steps [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 455 [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 863 [:db_insert_placeholder_13] => article [:db_insert_placeholder_14] => 2 [:db_insert_placeholder_15] => und 
[:db_insert_placeholder_16] => Wild Roses: fiori che sembrano appena sbocciati, che sottolineano ancora una volta la sua grande cifra stilistica, composizioni perfette per ogni dolce e speciale occasione. 
[:db_insert_placeholder_17] => full_html ) in image_field_caption_field_attach_update() (line 234 of /sites/all/modules/image_field_caption/image_field_caption.module).
```

But, as you can see, the :db_insert_placeholder_16 is valorized.
Can someone locate where the error is?
I can't find it..

Thank you ^^

Comment: What I can't understand is that you only have 9 table fields, but there are 18 (double) placeholders. That is where your bug is. Can't tell you why, but might be a clue. If I have to guess to a possible error is that you run the above code in a hook when the node is saved, and you save node again within that hook, causing a recursive problem (As I said, I'm only guessing)

Answer (score 1):

in the log entry it shows that `[:db_insert_placeholder_7]` and `[:db_insert_placeholder_8]` elements of the Array were empty - that might be the reason why **Insert** statement failed for the `caption` field:

```
Array 
( 
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => field_steps 
[:db_insert_placeholder_1] => node 
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 455 
[:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 863 
[:db_insert_placeholder_4] => article 
[:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0 
[:db_insert_placeholder_6] => und 
[:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_9] => field_steps 
[:db_insert_placeholder_10] => node 
[:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 455 
[:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 863 
[:db_insert_placeholder_13] => article 
[:db_insert_placeholder_14] => 2 
[:db_insert_placeholder_15] => und 
[:db_insert_placeholder_16] => Wild Roses: fiori che sembrano appena sbocciati, che sottolineano ancora una volta la sua grande cifra stilistica, composizioni perfette per ogni dolce e speciale occasione. 
[:db_insert_placeholder_17] => full_html 
) 
in image_field_caption_field_attach_update() (line 234 of /sites/all/modules/image_field_caption/image_field_caption.module).
```

also, [:db_insert_placeholder_16] - contains a string with 173 characters - is the `caption` field big enough?

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, you can use **[system_retrieve_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7)**

> **system_retrieve_file** - It will download a file from a remote source,
>   copy it from temp to a specified destination and optionally save it to
>   the file_managed table if you want it to be managed.

```
  $node_info = node_load($nid);//load created node
  if(empty($node_info->field_image)){//assign only if the image field is empty
    $field_language = field_language('node', $node_info, 'field_image');//get image field language
    $url = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png';//image URL to save. If image already saved in the drupal system then get the file ID(fid)
    //I have used picture folder to store images using image field settings
    $file_info = system_retrieve_file($url, 'public://pictures/', TRUE);//storing image inside picture folder
    if($file_info->fid){//if fid exist then image is saved from URL.
        $node_info->field_image[$field_language]['0']['fid'] = $file_info->fid;//assign fid
        $node_info->field_image[$field_language]['0']['image_field_caption']['value'] = 'test caption';//assign caption
        $node_info->field_image[$field_language]['0']['image_field_caption']['format'] = 'full_html';//assign format
    }
    node_save($node_info);//update node
  }
```

Note:

- Change your image field name.
- If the image is already stored in the drupal system then get the file ID(fid) and assign it to the image field directly.

Comment: Wow... all of that code for just an image with a caption? Who the hell thought of this structure for Drupal anyways? Seems like we are going backwards here instead of forwards!